# Diborane reduction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reference-request, organic-reduction

I am stuck at a step in reduction of alkene using $\ce{B2H6}.$ I assume that step 1 is the addition of borane to alkene. After that a water molecule attacks $\ce{-BH2},$ it being a Lewis acid. Subsequently, the boron will depart and oxygen will remove a proton which gets attached to carbanion formed when boron exited.

This is what I think is happening, the sole reason to ask it here is because I am unable to find a mechanism online or from a book. Mostly, I stumble upon hydroboration which is of no use to me. Please correct my mechanism or guide me to a reliable source.

Comment: When you don't find good results, it often means that the search keywords are not appropriate. Use Google Scholar in such cases. I typed "mechanism of alkene reduction by diborane" in Google Scholar, and the second result is a >20 paged review. I don't have an answer but you can certainly start from there. Anything which is in a textbook is often 20-30 years old research. Here is the link to the review: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr60304a005

Comment: What are you talking about? You want to make triple bond diborane? With what base? This is at least weird...

Comment: @Mithoron I was talking about reduction by diborane

Comment: Aditya, I am not an organic chemist so I don't know the answer. My point was that the answer must be out there if you use the right keywords. Search this phrase "mechanism of hydroboration of alkenes". I see several papers right away some of them can be downloaded. It is definitely complex because I see lot of papers on this topic. Are you in a university of college?

Comment: I'm still in school , last year

Comment: For the time being I would say accept the reaction as a fact as shown in your textbook. Those research papers may be too advanced or complicated at this moment. All I can feel is that the mechanism is complex and perhaps undecided as yet. You can see nobody posted an answer.

Comment: You can find a simplest mechanism and more in here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/11%3A_Alkenes_and_Alkynes_II_-_Oxidation_and_Reduction_Reactions._Acidity_of_Alkynes/11.6%3A_Addition_of_Boron_Hydrides_to_Alkenes._Organoboranes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition of boron hydrides to alkenes or alkyne is a valuable reaction in organic chemistry. The reaction is called hydroboration that gives organoboron compounds, which are a valuable group of intermediates for other organic synthesis ([Chem.libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/11%3A_Alkenes_and_Alkynes_II_-_Oxidation_and_Reduction_Reactions._Acidity_of_Alkynes/11.6%3A_Addition_of_Boron_Hydrides_to_Alkenes._Organoboranes)). The simplest borane,  $\ce{BH3}$, exists as the dimer, $\ce{B2H6}$, or in complexed form with certain ethers (*e.g.*, $\ce{H3B}$-THF) or sulfides (*e.g.*, $\ce{H3B-S(CH3)2}$). To my understanding, your expectation is to find a mechanism for hydroboration of an alkene by borane followed by its oxidation to corresponding alcohol. I found a suitable mechanism for that online and depicted in following diagram. First step is common hydroboration.

[image: Hydroboration]

Comment: No I was looking for a mechanism that converts alkene to alkane , instead of oxidation as the second step if an acid is used instead in aqueous medium then the mechanism follows the process I described  in my question, fortunately I could find it in the link given by you itself , so thank you.